# What is wrong with this simple calculator app using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

```
<html ng-app="Myapp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator App </h1>
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input1" ></input>
            <span ng-bind="ctrl.selectedOperation"></span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input2" ></input>
            <button onclick="ctrl.compute()">=</button>
            <span ng-bind="ctrl.resultValue"></span>

            <p>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.ButtonClicked('+')">+</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.ButtonClicked('-')">-</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.ButtonClicked('*')">*</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.ButtonClicked('/')">/</button>
            </p>

        </div>    
    <body>            
</html>    

app.js:------

var app = angular.module("Myapp",[]);

app.controller("myCtrl",myCtrl);

function myCtrl(){
    this.resultValue = 0;

   this.ButtonClicked = function(button){
    this.selectedOperation = button;
   }
    this.compute = function(){


        var number1 = parseFloat(this.input1);
        var number2 = parseFloat(this.input2);

        if(this.selectedOperation ==='+')
        {
            this.resultValue = number1 + number2;

        }else   if(this.selectedOperation ==='-')
        {
            this.resultValue = number1 - number2; 

        }else   if(this.selectedOperation ==='*')
        {
            this.resultValue = number1 * number2;

        }else   if(this.selectedOperation ==='/')
        {
            this.resultValue = number1 / number2; 
        }

    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in Angular JS and I'm learning it from Java Brains Youtube channel.

app.js is JavaScript file which is linked to html file, I tried everything but it's not working.

Comment: When you say not working, how is it not working? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Does an answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This html fragment:

```
<button onclick="ctrl.compute()">=</button>
```

should use the `ng-click` directive instead of the `onclick` property of button.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `onclick` on your button instead of `ng-click`.

So you just have to change:

```
<button onclick="ctrl.compute()">=</button>
```

To:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.compute()">=</button>
```

**[JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/4vr7940q/)**